# eclipselink change schema at EntityManager callbacks

Tags: postgresql, eclipselink, glassfish-3, saas, multi-tenant

i have a **multi-tenant** application and i need to **change the schema name at runtime** so it is gonna be shared DB seperate schema **SaaS** design.

because creating an EntityManagerFactory is very expensive, i would like to create the EMF application-scoped and specify the schema before every DB calls after initiating the EntityManger. i am using **Postgresql** 8.1 and because Postgesql doesn't support schema selection at setting up the DB connection, i thought the only way to query from tables for different schemas is querying '**SET search_path = "my.schema"**' before making the required DB calls.

i have tried;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                
sb.append("SET search_path TO my.schema");            
entityManager_.createNativeQuery(sb.toString()).executeUpdate();
```

i have got an exception saying '**java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot call executeUpdate() on this query.  It is the incorrect query type**'

i am using **eclipselink** as PersistenceProvider and **glassfish** as application manager

is there anyway i can get this done ?

i am open to any suggesstions if there is a better way of accomplishing this

thanks in advance

Comment: how'd this go? Are you still around?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing tenant-per-schema, are you also using tenant specific database login roles (user IDs)? If so, you can bind a default search path to your user:

```
ALTER USER thetenant SET search_path = 'thetenant';
```

If you also:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA thetenant FROM public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA thetenant TO tenant;
```

you will isolate the users from each other to a much greater extent, though they'll still see stuff in `pg_catalog` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

This requires you to use a login role per tenant. This can be difficult where connection pooling is in play because Java connection pools can't usually switch the user ID of a pooled connection and have to keep one pool per user Id. PostgresSQL's [`SET SESSION AUTHORISATION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html) statement can be useful, allowing you to log in as a single master user then switch to the user you need for a particular job, but I don't know if any Java pools support it directly. You can use external connection pools like PgBouncer and PgPool-II that are `SET SESSION AUTHORISATION` aware, or see if there's any way to write an interceptor so you can issue a `SET SESSION AUTHORISATION` on connections as they're checked out from the pool, and `RESET SESSION AUTHORISATION` when they're checked back in.

Even if you can't use role-based access, I'd try the same approach with your search path: see if you can do it with the connection pooler's help by trapping connections as they're checked out of the pool for a task, and as they're checked back in at release. How to do this would depend on the connection pool, though, and you may not want to get into the specifics of that.

BTW, why on earth are you using such a prehistoric version of PostgreSQL?

I don't know why EclipseLink is refusing your command. At face value it looks reasonable. Are you using ancient versions of other things, too? Which Glassfish and EclipseLink versions are you using?

Comment: Docs for the 8.1 version here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html

Comment: for now, i don't have tenant specific database login roles, the only DB user is 'postgres', will have to implement it later on tho. i will try to upgrade Postgresql to v9.* but i need to figure out what is causing the problem. i think it is how eclipselink sets up the DB connection because on the command line 'SET search_path' works as expected. i have tried to make this DB call after i start the transaction and after i initiated the EM but neither worked and the exception is above. Other than PG, i am using up-to-date versions of the tools. i will update post after the DB upgrade, thanks

Comment: When you say "other than Pg" do you include PgJDBC? ie, are you using an ancient PgJDBC, or are you using `9.1-902 JDBC 4` ? You should really specify exact versions, btw, since "current" now isn't clear when someone else is looking at this question 6 months down the track.

Comment: I am using the 9.1-902 JDBC4 driver so other than the PG server which is 8.1 every tool I am using is up-to-date. Eclipselink 2.3, glassfish 3.1 and JPA 2.0. Because DB server migration is not as easy and I didn't think the problem is that I haven't upgraded it but if what I am trying to do is doable with the newer version of PG, I will upgrade it and share the results, thanks for the answers

Comment: Cool. DB updates won't be easy from 8.1, you're right. You'll have particular problems with the removal of the implicit cast to text. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/release-8-3.html  http://www.depesz.com/2008/05/05/error-operator-does-not-exist-integer-text-how-to-fix-it/ http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com.au/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Version_History

Comment: hey, Postgresql upgrade to 9.* is gonna be more painful than i thought  but if you think what i am trying will work with the v9.*, i will spend more time on it or if you have any other ideas about how i can get this done (being able to query 'SET SEARCH_PATH="my.schema"'), it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, `set search_path = 'my_schema';` should work the way you seem to be invoking it and I'm surprised you're having issues. Time permitting I'll try to put together a minimal test case JPA project to demo this and make sure. As for the DB move: You need to move anyway, because PostgreSQL 8.1 is dropping out of support and in any case you're missing LOTS of enhancements/fixes/performance improvements. Still, you shouldn't have to move to 9.x just for this one problem.

Comment: i would appreciate if you can give me any feedback from your minimal test case, i will be digging the problem as well. You are right i should upgrade PostgreSQL anytime soon but as you can guess, there is gonna be lots of rpm dependencies, Centos 6 stuff so i will try to get it working on the existing system first then move forward. thanks in advance

Comment: @JoeJavac Re RPM: Easiest way to upgrade if stuck on an old "Enterprise" distro is to use the PostgreSQL binary installers packaged by EnterpriseDB, or use http://yum.postgresql.org/ . Will report back re testcase if I get the time to build one.